# Hibernate/SQL Retrieve records without returning the associations

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I want to retrieve the records from a table without its associations mentioned in the entity. How to do this using Hibernate?

I want to get the record in Animal table without trying to retrieve the Breed in the below example.

Below are the associations i have:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ANIMAL")
public class Animal {
private Long id;
private String type;
private String subtype;
private String category;    
private Set<Breed> associatedBreeds = new HashSet<Breed>();

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idSeq")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "idSeq", sequenceName = "ID_SEQ")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

@Column(name = "TYPE")
public String getType() {
    return type;
}

@Column(name = "SUBTYPE")
public String getSubtype() {
    return subtype;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public void setSubtype(String subtype) {
    this.subtype = subtype;
}

public void setCategory(String category) {
    this.category = category;
}

@Column(name = "CATEGORY", insertable = false, updatable = false)   
public String getCategory() {
    return category;
}

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "propertyUsage", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = { CascadeType.ALL })
public Set<Breed> getAssociatedBreeds() {
    return associatedBreeds;
}

public void setAssociatedBreeds(
        Set<Breed> associatedFinancials) {
    this.associatedBreeds = associatedBreeds;
}
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Breed")
public class Breed {
private Long id;

private Animal animal;

@Id
@Column(name = "ID")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "idSeq1")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "idSeq1", sequenceName = "ID_SEQ1")
public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setPropertyUsage(PropertyUsage propertyUsage) {
    this.animal = animal;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ANIMAL_ID", referencedColumnName="ID")    
public PropertyUsage getAnimal() {
    return animal;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the @OneToMany annotation of your getAssociatedBreeds() method you set the fetch property to EAGER. Change this to LAZY. This will cause your associated elements not to be loaded until you actually access them.

Comment: I tried this earlier and it still executes the queries on the database. I do not what the query to be executed on the database too because i also want to save some performance on the query execution on the database.

Comment: Does any of your code call the getAssociatedBreeds() method? Or do your Animal entities somehow get serialized, maybe because they are sent to a remote UI layer?

Comment: I ran the test in debug mode, when the findByCriteria happens, at this time itself i see the logs and the queries have been executed to retrieve related records.  Now, there is a call to getAssociatedBreeds down the line before the completion if the request. There is no serialization happening in this case for UI layer.

Comment: ok, i think i overlooked some things last time. I see that the Lazy is working right as you mentioned. Right now, i am getting an exception for "no session or session closed". I read the documentation  and looks like i need to add @Transactional so that LAZY Can work. So, on the caller i added this annotation. Now, i am still getting the same exception. Looks like i am putting the Annotation in the wrong place. Please suggest.

Comment: Call Structure is:                                                                              service -> (calls) -> hibernateMethod -> (calls) -> hibernatetemplate.get()                                            The child association is being accessed in the service. I have added the @Transactional annotation on the service method.

Comment: Are you accessing the Entities from your view?

Comment: These entities are all tables.

Comment: I got this working by deferring the Connection to be closed using the API: SessionFactoryUtils.initDeferredClose(hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory());

Answer (score 1):

Change the fetch type to lazy fetch = FetchType.LAZY This will make hibernate not pull the breeds until they are requested or used and not when the Animal object is created

Comment: I tried this earlier and it still executes the queries on the database. I do not what the query to be executed on the database too because i also want to save some performance on the query execution on the database.

Comment: I got this working using LAZY and by delaying the connection to be closed. Thanks for the response and help.